# ASP.Net MVC3 remote validation with multiple values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

This MSDN article talks about using remove validation to validate a single value....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

In particular, the model properties are attributed so that remove validation is invoked ...

```
public class CreateUserModel : EditUserModel {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Remote("IsUID_Available", "Validation")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is remote validation where a number of fields are taken into account. For example I may want to submit two or three fields in an Ajax manner and get back an overall validation result.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you need to validate against multiple values aren't you validating the form rather than just a field? Are these multiple values part of the form?

Comment: Yes they are part of the same form.

Answer (score 5):

You could set the [`AdditionalFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.additionalfields.aspx) property of the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.aspx) attribute in order to have other property values sent to the action.

```
[Remote("IsUID_Available", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Email")]
public override string UserName { get; set; }
```

and then inside your controller action:

```
public ActionResult IsUID_Available(string username, string email)
{
    ...
}
```