# how to use single validation for two controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to validate two textbox controls, in which at least one textbox should be filled before submit.Is there any solution for this issue. Please help me

```
<asp:TextBox ID=" txtMobileNo " runat="server>" </asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regMobilNo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobileNo" ErrorMessage="Invalid Mobile No" CssClass="valField" ValidationExpression="^[789]\d{9}$" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>  

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSendEmail" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="regmail" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSendEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" ValidationGroup=" reg " CssClass="valField" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: why don't you use jquery for validation?

Comment: i knew it is possible with jquery. Is there any way to solve this problem from server side

Comment: Can u share html of the page.

Comment: are these textbox depends on each other. like if you fill one then other needs to be filled. like conditional validation?

Comment: at least one field should be filled from two fields

Comment: check my answer below it will help you.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Finally I used textchanged events for showing the required and regular expression warning messages in labels

Comment: check out this answer by kgoogling https://forums.asp.net/t/1209510.aspx?One+Required+Field+Validator+on+Multiple+Controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay within the asp.net validation framework, you would need two validators, but you could use a javascript function to unify the logic.

```
<asp:TextBox ID=" txtMobileNo " runat="server>" </asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="regMobilNo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobileNo" ErrorMessage="Invalid Mobile No" CssClass="valField"  ClientValidationFunction="checkTexts" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" ></asp:CustomValidator >  


<asp:TextBox ID="txtSendEmail" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="regmail" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSendEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" ValidationGroup=" reg " CssClass="valField" ClientValidationFunction="checkTexts" ></asp:CustomValidator >
```

And a javascript function like this:

```
function checkTexts {
firstText = getelementbyid('<%=txtMobileNo.ClientID %>');
secondText = getelementbyid('<%=txtSendEmail.ClientID %>');
// do stuff
// return true or false
}
```

If you really want server validation, the custom validator can also specify a server function (which can be the same between the two validators), but client-side validation is almost always to be preferred, unless doing so could expose sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery which you can use suppose you have text1 and text2 textboxes then

```
var txt1= jQuery.trim($("#text1").val());
var txt2= jQuery.trim($("#text2").val());

if(txt1=="" and txt2="")
{
   alert("you message");
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem using server side validation

Comment: You can use [custom validator](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_customvalidator.asp) with javascript funciton.

Comment: But how to set controltovalidate property for two controls?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I assume that you have two textbox controls and if you fill one the other textbox become optional. I think simpliest solution to this is on the **text change** event of the either of the textbox you can set required field validator enabled/disabled for the second one. Like shown here:

```
reqFirstname.Enabled = txtFirstname.Text == "Fred";
```

I am not clear about your requirement here. The solution above is assuming that you are using asp.net web form. For asp.net mvc there is already a library which can do that on the fly. Let me know if you are facing different issue other than solution provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Try remote validation

```
[Remote("Validation", "Home", AdditionalFields = "value2")]
public String value1 { get; set; }
```

In controller

```
public JsonResult Validation(string value1, string value2 )
{
// Do the validation
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590571/2501044

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript then you can create a function:-

```
private bool checktextbox()
{
 if(textbox1.text!="")
 {
  return true
 }
 else if(textbox2.text!="")
 {
  return true
 }
 else 
 {
  return false
 }    
}
```

and call on your button click event like

```
if(checktextbox())
{
//your code
}
else{
//through error that atleat one text box should be filled
}
```